# Calculate the residue of $\cot\pi z$ at poles $z=n$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, residue-calculus

I'm having trouble calculating the residue of $f(z) =\cot\pi z$. The function has  a simple pole for every integer n, and i'm, trying to find the residue at n.

I know that by the residue theorem: $$\text{Res}(\cos\pi z,n) = \lim_{z\rightarrow n} ( z-n) f(z) $$
And i know (well i think) that the answer is:

$$\text{Res}(\cos\pi z,n) = \frac{\cos\pi n}{\pi \cos\pi n} $$
However i'm completely stuck with how to use the simple pole residue theorem, and how to sub in, or what  i do with the theorem to show that this is the answer.  Do i need to integrate anything ? or something similar?

Any help welcome! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \text{Res}[\cot (\pi z), n] &= \lim_{z \to n} \ (z-n) \cot (\pi z) \\ &= \lim_{z \to n} \ (z-n) \frac{\cos (\pi z)}{\sin (\pi z)} \\ &= \lim_{z \to n} \frac{\cos \pi z - (z-n) \pi \sin (\pi z)}{\pi \cos (\pi z)} \ \ (\text{ L'Hospital's rule}) \\ &= \frac{\cos (\pi n)-0}{\pi \cos(\pi n)} \\&= \frac{1}{\pi} \end{align}$$

In general, if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic at $z=z_{0}$, $f(z_{0}) \ne 0$, and $g(z)$ has a simple zero at $z=z_{0}$, then

$$ \text{Res}\Big[ \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}, z_{0} \Big] = \frac{f(z_{0})}{g'(z_{0})}.$$

Comment: why did you make derivative for $f(z)=(z-n)(cos(\pi z))$ ? shouldn't you make derivative for $g(z)=sin z$ only and then calculate for $z_0$

Comment: I applied L'Hospital's rule in order to evaluate the limit $\lim_{z \to n} (z-n) \, \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$, where $f(z) = \cos (\pi z)$ and $g(z) = \sin(\pi z)$. I didn't' directly apply that theorem. But in general, if the conditions I stated above are satisfied, then$$ \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}, z_{0} \right] =\lim_{z \to z_{0}} (z-z_{0}) \,  \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z \to z_{0}}\frac{f(z) +(z-z_{0})f'(z)}{g'(z)} = \frac{f(z_{0})}{g'(z_{0})}$$